# Changing crystal report crosstab column width

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

How can I change `column-width` in my cross tab according to the text of `column-length`?

The `Can grow` option is also disabled for cross tab columns.

Comment: do you want to adjust width of your cross tab columns dynamically or to change it just one time in a way to fit your data?

Comment: Need to change them dynamically

Comment: There is no option for dynamic column width in crosstab object. You can set a specific width at preview and that's it. Maybe using a css class could be a solution but I think this requires using asp .net